# Django ModelForm and AJAX usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

i am working on for a basic feedback system. I just want to submit feedback with ajax, for example if fields are empty ajax will return some error msg and update the div at the same page with no redirection. if everything is ok it will update the feedbacks div with the new one...

Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class FeedBack(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from submission.forms import *

def feedback(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FeedBackForm(request.POST)
        message = 'Oops!'
        if(form.is_valid()):
            message = request.POST['title']
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))

    return render_to_response('index.html',
            {'form':FeedBackForm()}, RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from submission.views import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^feedback/', feedback, name='feed_back'),
)
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/helper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Leave a Suggestion Here</h1>
    <div class="message"></div>
    <div>
        <form id="feed_form" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Feedback" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

helper.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feed_form').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
            url: '', // the file to call
            success: function(data) { // on success..
                $('.message').html(data); // update the DIV
            },
            error: function(e, x, r) { // on error..
                $('.message').html(e); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: please note your issue exactly and also it may be helpful to provide your project's directory structure.
Also use `static` package in `index.html` instead of hardcoded addresses!

Comment: I mean sth like `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'helper.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: the problem is the json message is not loading at the same time, form goes away and just {"message":"Oops!"} is staying... (if u post it blank, if u post it with title and desc. {"message": "..."})

Comment: dont do " import * "

Comment: form is not validating here.